# Is there any way to refer to, or convert a thread object as a string?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

i am currently playing with an echo server and echo client which was provided fundamentally by my lecturer. each client connects to a socket thread which is started by start() in the EchoServer class. anyway i put the line "System.out.println(this);"  within the loop in the server class.
Thankfully this gives the output "Thread[Thread-0,5,main]","Thread[Thread-1,5,main]", depending on which thread it is, the first or second respectively.  I want to be able to say:

```
if (this == "Thread[Thread-1,5,main]"){

do so and so
}else{
do so and so
}
```

However "Thread[Thread-1,5,main]" is not a string so is there a way i can refer to the current thread as a string or how can i refer to it or convert it?

also sorry for not sharing the code im just not sure if it is lawful considering it belongs to  my lecturer.

Comment: Instead of comparing strings, why not just compare the instance of `java.lang.Thread` that is `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for [`Thread#getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getName--) and [`Thread#setName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setName-java.lang.String-).

However, as hexafraction pointed out, if you have references to the threads, just do the comparison directly:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(/*...*/);
Thread t2 = new Thread(/*...*/);

// ...later...

if (Thread.currentThread() == t1) {
    // It's t1
}
```

[`Thread.currentThread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread--) returns a reference to the currently-executing thread.